# What happens when a texture is too large for a device

Tags: opengl, unity, textures, texture-atlas

The question is two fold:

1. What happens on a device when a texture is too large for it to handle? Will it crash or simply downsize it?
2. In Unity if I use texture atlases of size 4k and then set `Texture Quality` in the `Quality settings` as **half res** will it run normally on devices with maximum texture size of 2k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/162453-max-texture-size-at-run-time) automatic downsizing may not work, but setting half res should work.

On a related note, do you really need textures that big? If all you want from a big texture is to use it as an atlas there is really very little reason to not just use 4 2k textures instead of one 4k.

And I assume that this is about writing games for phones, for PC graphics anything that doesn't support 4k textures is really ancient.

Comment: The thing with 4k atlases is that you can fit more objects into a single draw call when batching. And yes, mobile devices are the target.

Comment: @Esa If you end up with 4 draw calls instead of 1 I wouldn't think it's a big performance impact. You better avoid hundreds or thousands of draw calls, but most likely this isn't going to be much of a dent in your performance.